# Changing Text file name through C

Tags: c, file-io

I plan to edit some data of the text file and here is what I plan to do:

1) Read the original content of the file , get the data of the file using Singly-linked list then close the file

2) Re-open the file but now with "w+" then get the edited data then close file

3) use `fprintf` to write to a New file that contains the edited data

4) Get the original content of the file then put them into the New file.

5) Change the New File's name into the Original content file name

Now, how do you change the name of the text file?

My plan sounds ridiculous, I know:

Q: Why do you plan to change the name of the New File when you can just make the edit happen in the original file?

A: I tried putting the edited data into the original file using "w+" and I got lost in the part where I need to get the content of the Original file and put them again into the original file.

Thanks!

Comment: [`man 3 rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`rename(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) function to rename files.  If you're on Windows and need to support Unicode filenames, you can should use the [`MoveFileExW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function; but if you only need to rename ANSI filenames, use `rename()` instead since it's more portable.

Comment: @user2882762: It's quite simple: `rename("oldfilename.txt", "newfilename.txt");`

Answer (score -1):

You can just use a system call. In linux, it would be something like:

```
system("mv old-file-name new-file-name");
```

Comment: It works, but..... it spawns a shell. This means that you need to escape any meta characters. It's better to just use rename from stdio or go old school and use link to create a hard link inode and unlink to remove the original inode.

Comment: That's true, I have to admit I wasn't aware of the existence of `rename()` function, and tended to do these manipulation with files using system calls, which is obviously inefficient and a barrier to portability.